# How do I include GLFW 3.x, without errors?

Tags: c++, c, linker, static-linking, glfw

I have downloaded GLFW 3.1.1(glfw-3.1.1.zip) to my computer.

I want to execute this code:

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

In other words, I just want to be able to include GLFW in my code, so that I later on can open a context (for openGL use).

But I get this error message when running the code:

```
Error   1   error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLFW/glfw3.h': No such file or directory    f:\opengl_coding\video_tut_test\video_tut_test\main.cpp 1   1   Video_tut_test
```

I know that there is a step that I haven't done, but I don't understand what this step is. Is it linking? I see this being talked a lot about in tutorials, but they never explain it properly.

How do I remove the error and make it possible to execute the above code?

I use Visual Studio Express 2013, on a Windows 8 machine.
I come from a Java background.

Comment: You need to edit your project settings to mention the include directory that contains the "`GLFW`" directory.

Comment: @BrianCain Where do I edit these settings?

Comment: I tried adjusting project settings: "C\C++" -> "General" -> "Additional include Directories" -> set to the folder "glfw-3.1.1\include\GLFW". But I get the same error message.